# finding the greatest Fibonacci number within limited time in python

Tags: python

I need a code that calculates nth fibonacci number as well as giving me the time used to calculate it, in python.

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0 or n==1: return 1
    else: return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

The calculation of the number step must use a such method.

Comment: First, please format your code correctly.  Edit the question. The formatting rules are on the bottom right.  Second, please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.  Finally, please post the code you tried to use and the errors you got.  We don't like doing your homework for you.  But we will answer specific questions.

Comment: please put the code text in code blocks using the **{}** button.

Comment: use of recursion to perform this calculation results in terrible performance

Comment: @David Heffernan: unless you memoise.

Comment: since I'm very new to this place I didn't know about the tagging and other specifications, and although this is related to my homework it is not the homework itself. I asked this way because it is the simplest way to approach since I had no idea what I might start with, also I don't like others doing my homework. anyway, thank you for the help.

Comment: @katrielalex avoiding recursion and using a simple loop with a couple of working variables is still going to be much much faster

Comment: @David: But then again, fibonacci numbers aren't the kind of thing you have to calculate in hot loops (or in any real-world application, for that matter). It's homework for excercise with recursion, not for a benchmark.

Comment: @ozgur fib(0) should return 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module to time the function:

```
import timeit

def fib(x):
    if x==0 or x==1: return 1
    else: return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2)

print timeit.Timer('fib(5)', 'from __main__ import fib').timeit()
```

Output:

```
3.12172317505
```

To directly answer the question in the title, you can use [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) to get the current time since the epoch in seconds and keep calculating the subsequent fibonacci number until the time limit is reached. I've chosen to use an efficient method of computing fibonacci numbers below to give you a better demonstrating of this concept.

```
def fibTimeLimited(limit):
  start = time.time()
  n, f0, f1 = 1, 0, 1
  while time.time() < start + limit:
    n += 1
    f0, f1 = f1, f0+f1
  return (n, f1)
```

Sample output:

```
Calculated 1st fibonacci number as 1 in 0.000001 seconds
Calculated 31st fibonacci number as 1346269 in 0.000010 seconds
Calculated 294th fibonacci number as 12384578529797304192493293627316781267732493780359086838016392 in 0.000100 seconds
```

Comment: but one last thing, this is milliseconds right? also the time that takes to give the output, for like lets say x=8, is quite much, why?

Comment: @ozgur The output is in nanoseconds, which is 1/1000th of a millisecond. @katriealex's answer explains why this is so slow for even small numbers and how to speed it up.

Comment: speeding up is not really a concern right now, I was just curious about the reason that it was being slow, again, thank you

Comment: @David You are correct, however, OP has stated many times now he only cares about getting runtime, so I am not focussing on edge cases or performance.

Answer (score 7):

This is a classic dynamic programming/recursion with memoization problem. Notice that in your code, you recursively call `fib(x-1)` a *lot*. This is a huge waste of effort: once you calculate it once, you should store it for later use so that you don't have to calculate it again. In Python 3 you can do this with the glorious [`functools.lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Unfortunately, since nobody uses Python 3.2 yet, you'll have to write your own. Here's some pseudocode:

```
cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}
def fib(n):
    if n in cache:
        return the cached value
    else:
        calculate fib(n) recursively
        store the value in the cache
        return the value
```

This technique is known as recursion with memoization. Equivalently, you can use *dynamic programming*: calculate the values from the bottom up:

```
fibs = [0, 1]
for i in range(2, n):
    calculate fibs[i] using the previous values in fibs
    append the new value
```

---

To time these functions, put them in a module (a file ending in `.py`) and use `timeit` from the command line:

```
(change directory to the one containing your module)
python -mtimeit "import <name of module>" "fib(3000)"
```

---

By the way, there is a closed-form expression for the nth Fibonacci number, which may prove faster/more useful:

[image: Binet's formula]

where

[image: definition of phi]

Comment: +1 lru_cache sounds awesome, never come across it before, thanks!

Comment: It's Memoization not memorisation.

Comment: that cache is great, thanks for that but I need to use this fib(x-1) only. therefore speed is not an issue. still it's a great post!

Comment: @ozgur: I'm not sure I understand your claim. Think about what happens when you calculate `fib(4)`: you calculate `fib(3)`, which requires `fib(2)` (which requires `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`) and `fib(2)`, which you have already worked out! The cache ensures you don't repeat yourself. If you draw a tree diagram for `fib(10)` or so, you will see how any branches are duplicated.

Comment: @razpeitia sorry, my bad, now fixed, will now learn to butt out!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example that uses Python tuples instead of recursion.

```
import time

def fib(n):
    cnt = 1
    if n == 0:
        return a
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while n > cnt:
        (a, b) = (b, b+a)
        cnt += 1
    return b

start = time.time()
result = fib(15)
runTime = time.time() - start

print result, runTime
```

Comment: @Abizern -1 The basic idea is reasonable, it's just a shame that it gets the answers wrong

Comment: @David - Changed the initial count variable. Now gives 610 for F15. Have I missed anything else?

Comment: @David - I appreciate the reversal. And I wouldn't have been offended if you edited the code to correct it. :)

Comment: @Abizern Nearly. The original question and the accepted answer and your answer all return 1 for fib(0) when in fact 0 is correct.

Comment: @Abizerm this whole question illustrates how important it is to write some tests when developing code. There are more incorrect implementations of fib than correct ones. By heck some of them run fast, but it's not hard to get the wrong answer quickly!!

Comment: @David. And another correction. You make me want to climb into the safety of my Objective-C box :-)